# Python зависание multiprocessing

Tags: python

Установил Анаконду с Спайдером. Беру код из туториала

```
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    def f(x):
        return x*x
    print(pool.map(f, range(10)))
```

В итоге ничего не выполняется и все зависает. Что делать?

Comment: Этот код не может зависать, он обязан выдать ошибку `NameError: name 'pool' is not defined`, так что вы что-то не договариваете

Comment: @andreymal: у меня в файле только этот код, когда нажимаю пуск, то у меня бесконечно показывается значок загрузки. Нажатие на стоп никак не помогает, только закрытие консоли. Я бы скинул скриншот, да не знаю как приложить.

Comment: Значит дело вообще не в этом коде, потому что он просто обязан показать ошибку. Где, как и чем вы его запускаете? О каком значке загрузки речь? Если всё по какому-то туториалу — дайте на него ссылку, чтобы лучше понимать, о чём именно речь

Comment: @andreymal я установил Anaconda  и после Spider. В итоге начал писать самостоятельную работу, которую задали, после мне нужно было использовать multiprocessing. Но он не работал и я создал новый файл взял код отсюда https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html и понял что у меня просто все зависает. И отвисает если закрыть консоль и после автоматически подгружается новая. Значок загрузки я имел ввиду иконку мышки, которая изменяется в Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Вдруг поможет.

Note Functionality within this package requires that the **main** module be importable by the children. This is covered in Programming guidelines however it is worth pointing out here. This means that some examples, such as the multiprocessing.pool.Pool examples will not work in the interactive interpreter. For example:

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Pool
>>> p = Pool(5)
>>> def f(x):
...     return x*x
...
>>> p.map(f, [1,2,3])
Process PoolWorker-1:
Process PoolWorker-2:
Process PoolWorker-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'f'
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'f'
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'f'
```

(If you try this it will actually output three full tracebacks interleaved in a semi-random fashion, and then you may have to stop the master process somehow.)

### Вот ваш пример ---

```
The following example demonstrates the use of a pool:
```

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:         # start 4 worker processes
        result = pool.apply_async(f, (10,)) # evaluate "f(10)" asynchronously in a single process
        print(result.get(timeout=1))        # prints "100" unless your computer is *very* slow

        print(pool.map(f, range(10)))       # prints "[0, 1, 4,..., 81]"

        it = pool.imap(f, range(10))
        print(next(it))                     # prints "0"
        print(next(it))                     # prints "1"
        print(it.next(timeout=1))           # prints "4" unless your computer is *very* slow

        result = pool.apply_async(time.sleep, (10,))
        print(result.get(timeout=1))        # raises multiprocessing.TimeoutErro
```

Comment: @Wertartern Да, помогло. Спасибо большое!